# Can I click a button on a webpage if I only know certian info?

Tags: c#, browser

I want to click a button on a website. I know only the following information:

- Class of the button
- Value of the button
- Type of the button

None of these three things are used on the page, it's *only* the button that has these three things (meaning, a form has a the class "form" however the button has the class "button").

Comment: You need to further explain this. Do you mean the button has the attributes class, value and type?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

You can use Jquery selector if you know any unique attribute value of that button.
or you can use index of controls in form.

Answer (score 0):

You said you button element have a `className` ("button"),you can get this element with like this:

```
  public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            webBrowser1.Navigate("To your register account url");
        }
        int on = 0;
        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (HtmlElement btn in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button"))
            {
                if (btn.GetAttribute("className") == "button")
                {
                    btn.InvokeMember("Click");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

If you have `multiple button` with the `same class name` you can do this:

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            webBrowser1.Navigate("To your register account url");
        }
        int on = 0;
        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (HtmlElement btn in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button"))
            {
                if (btn.GetAttribute("className") == "button" && btn.InnerText=="your button value")
                {
                    btn.InvokeMember("Click");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

You'll have to know the name of the button and the name of the form.